# How to convert words to a number?

Tags: java

I want to convert words containing alphabetical characters into a representative number in Java.

For example, `four hundred four` should evaluate to the number `404`.

If the letters are gibberish like `asdf` then that's an error.

I know I can [convert bare Characters to their ascii equivalent Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388037/converting-characters-to-integers-in-java), appending those together, but I only want the numbers behind the English word phrases extracted.

Comment: What about "four hundred and four"?

Comment: That's a very difficult task when you consider all the possibilities. English allows for many kinds of ways to say the same thing, even with numbers. You might be better off coming up with a list of rules that you expect?

Comment: right now i just want numbers with no (and)s like i said e.g. four hundred four

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Sounds like a GREAT case for a huge `Enum`...

Comment: 15.141 times viewed that's not off topic ...

Answer (score 18):

Here is some code that I came up with when trying to solve the same problem. Keep in mind that I am not a professional and do not have insane amounts of experience. It is not slow, but I'm sure it could be faster/cleaner/etc. I used it in converting voice recognized words into numbers for calculation in my own "Jarvis" a la Iron Man. It can handle numbers under 1 billion, although it could easily be expanded to include much higher magnitudes at the cost of very little time.

```
public static final String[] DIGITS = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
public static final String[] TENS = {null, "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};
public static final String[] TEENS = {"ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"};
public static final String[] MAGNITUDES = {"hundred", "thousand", "million", "point"};
public static final String[] ZERO = {"zero", "oh"};

public static String replaceNumbers (String input) {
    String result = "";
    String[] decimal = input.split(MAGNITUDES[3]);
    String[] millions = decimal[0].split(MAGNITUDES[2]);

    for (int i = 0; i < millions.length; i++) {
        String[] thousands = millions[i].split(MAGNITUDES[1]);

        for (int j = 0; j < thousands.length; j++) {
            int[] triplet = {0, 0, 0};
            StringTokenizer set = new StringTokenizer(thousands[j]);

            if (set.countTokens() == 1) { //If there is only one token given in triplet
                String uno = set.nextToken();
                triplet[0] = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < DIGITS.length; k++) {
                    if (uno.equals(DIGITS[k])) {
                        triplet[1] = 0;
                        triplet[2] = k + 1;
                    }
                    if (uno.equals(TENS[k])) {
                        triplet[1] = k + 1;
                        triplet[2] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }


            else if (set.countTokens() == 2) {  //If there are two tokens given in triplet
                String uno = set.nextToken();
                String dos = set.nextToken();
                if (dos.equals(MAGNITUDES[0])) {  //If one of the two tokens is "hundred"
                    for (int k = 0; k < DIGITS.length; k++) {
                        if (uno.equals(DIGITS[k])) {
                            triplet[0] = k + 1;
                            triplet[1] = 0;
                            triplet[2] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    triplet[0] = 0;
                    for (int k = 0; k < DIGITS.length; k++) {
                        if (uno.equals(TENS[k])) {
                            triplet[1] = k + 1;
                        }
                        if (dos.equals(DIGITS[k])) {
                            triplet[2] = k + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            else if (set.countTokens() == 3) {  //If there are three tokens given in triplet
                String uno = set.nextToken();
                String dos = set.nextToken();
                String tres = set.nextToken();
                for (int k = 0; k < DIGITS.length; k++) {
                    if (uno.equals(DIGITS[k])) {
                        triplet[0] = k + 1;
                    }
                    if (tres.equals(DIGITS[k])) {
                        triplet[1] = 0;
                        triplet[2] = k + 1;
                    }
                    if (tres.equals(TENS[k])) {
                        triplet[1] = k + 1;
                        triplet[2] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            else if (set.countTokens() == 4) {  //If there are four tokens given in triplet
                String uno = set.nextToken();
                String dos = set.nextToken();
                String tres = set.nextToken();
                String cuatro = set.nextToken();
                for (int k = 0; k < DIGITS.length; k++) {
                    if (uno.equals(DIGITS[k])) {
                        triplet[0] = k + 1;
                    }
                    if (cuatro.equals(DIGITS[k])) {
                        triplet[2] = k + 1;
                    }
                    if (tres.equals(TENS[k])) {
                        triplet[1] = k + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                triplet[0] = 0;
                triplet[1] = 0;
                triplet[2] = 0;
            }

            result = result + Integer.toString(triplet[0]) + Integer.toString(triplet[1]) + Integer.toString(triplet[2]);
        }
    }

    if (decimal.length > 1) {  //The number is a decimal
        StringTokenizer decimalDigits = new StringTokenizer(decimal[1]);
        result = result + ".";
        System.out.println(decimalDigits.countTokens() + " decimal digits");
        while (decimalDigits.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String w = decimalDigits.nextToken();
            System.out.println(w);

            if (w.equals(ZERO[0]) || w.equals(ZERO[1])) {
                result = result + "0";
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < DIGITS.length; j++) {
                if (w.equals(DIGITS[j])) {
                    result = result + Integer.toString(j + 1);
                }   
            }

        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Input must be in grammatically correct syntax, otherwise it will have issues (create a function to remove "and"). A string input of "two hundred two million fifty three thousand point zero eight five eight oh two" returns:

```
two hundred two million fifty three thousand point zero eight five eight oh two
202053000.085802
It took 2 milliseconds.
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer is a great save timer!

However, field TEENS are never used -  this won't recognise strings like "eleven".

This is easy to fix - for example, in the first if block add
 if (uno.equals(TENS[k])) triplet[2] =k+10;

Comment: @smihael do you mean to add:
`if (uno.equals(TEENS[k])) triplet[2] =k+10;` (with `TEENS` rather than `TENS`)?

Answer (score 12):

The basic strategy would be to have a `value` variable that you work with.  Each time you see a string "one", "two", "eleven", "seventy" you would add that amount to `value`.  When you see a string like "hundred", "thousand", "million", you would *multiply* `value` by that amount.

For larger numbers you'll probably need to create a few subtotals and combine at the end.  The steps to process a number like 111,374 written out as "one hundred eleven thousand three hundred seventy four" would be

- "one" -> `value[0] += 1` (now `1`)
- "hundred" -> `value[0] *= 100` (now `100`)
- "eleven" -> `value[0] += 11` (now `111`)
- "thousand" -> `value[0] *= 1000` (now `111000`)
- "three" -> `value[1] += 3`
- "hundred" -> `value[1] *= 100` (now `300`)
- "seventy" -> `value[1] += 70` (now `370`)
- "four" -> `value[1] += 4` now (374)

You'll still need to figure out how to decide when to build it as multiple values. It appears you should start a new subtotal when you encounter a multiplier ("hundred") which is *smaller* than the most recently seen multiplier.

Comment: You might want to put all the words into a `string szWords[]`. So, `szWords[0] = "one hundred thousand"`, `szWords[1] = "eleven hundred thousand"`, `szWords[2] = "three hundred"`, `szWords[3] = "seventy"`, `szWords[4] = "four"`

Comment: @muntoo - it's not clear what your suggestion is supposed to accomplish

Answer (score 5):

```
public class InNumerals5Digits {

static String testcase1 = "ninety nine thousand nine hundred ninety nine";//

public static void main(String args[]){
    InNumerals5Digits testInstance = new InNumerals5Digits();
    int result = testInstance.inNumerals(testcase1);
    System.out.println("Result : "+result);
}

//write your code here
public int inNumerals(String inwords)
{
    int wordnum = 0;
    String[] arrinwords = inwords.split(" ");
    int arrinwordsLength = arrinwords.length;
    if(inwords.equals("zero"))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(inwords.contains("thousand"))
    {
        int indexofthousand = inwords.indexOf("thousand");
        //System.out.println(indexofthousand);
        String beforethousand = inwords.substring(0,indexofthousand);
        //System.out.println(beforethousand);
        String[] arrbeforethousand = beforethousand.split(" ");
        int arrbeforethousandLength = arrbeforethousand.length;
        //System.out.println(arrbeforethousandLength);
        if(arrbeforethousandLength==2)
        {
            wordnum = wordnum + 1000*(wordtonum(arrbeforethousand[0]) + wordtonum(arrbeforethousand[1]));
            //System.out.println(wordnum);
        }
        if(arrbeforethousandLength==1)
        {
            wordnum = wordnum + 1000*(wordtonum(arrbeforethousand[0]));
            //System.out.println(wordnum);
        }

    }
    if(inwords.contains("hundred"))
    {
        int indexofhundred = inwords.indexOf("hundred");
        //System.out.println(indexofhundred);
        String beforehundred = inwords.substring(0,indexofhundred);

        //System.out.println(beforehundred);
        String[] arrbeforehundred = beforehundred.split(" ");
        int arrbeforehundredLength = arrbeforehundred.length;
        wordnum = wordnum + 100*(wordtonum(arrbeforehundred[arrbeforehundredLength-1]));
        String afterhundred = inwords.substring(indexofhundred+8);//7 for 7 char of hundred and 1 space
        //System.out.println(afterhundred);
        String[] arrafterhundred = afterhundred.split(" ");
        int arrafterhundredLength = arrafterhundred.length;
        if(arrafterhundredLength==1)
        {
            wordnum = wordnum + (wordtonum(arrafterhundred[0]));
        }
        if(arrafterhundredLength==2)
        {
            wordnum = wordnum + (wordtonum(arrafterhundred[1]) + wordtonum(arrafterhundred[0]));
        }
        //System.out.println(wordnum);

    }
    if(!inwords.contains("thousand") && !inwords.contains("hundred"))
    {
        if(arrinwordsLength==1)
        {
            wordnum = wordnum + (wordtonum(arrinwords[0]));
        }
        if(arrinwordsLength==2)
        {
            wordnum = wordnum + (wordtonum(arrinwords[1]) + wordtonum(arrinwords[0]));
        }
        //System.out.println(wordnum);
    }


    return wordnum;
}   


public int wordtonum(String word)
{
        int num = 0;
        switch (word) {
            case "one":  num = 1;
                     break;
            case "two":  num = 2;
                     break;
            case "three":  num = 3;
                     break;
            case "four":  num = 4;
                     break;
            case "five":  num = 5;
                     break;
            case "six":  num = 6;
                     break;
            case "seven":  num = 7;
                     break;
            case "eight":  num = 8;
                     break;
            case "nine":  num = 9;
                     break;
            case "ten": num = 10;
                     break;
            case "eleven": num = 11;
                     break;
            case "twelve": num = 12;
                     break;
            case "thirteen": num = 13;
                     break;
            case "fourteen": num = 14;
                     break;             
            case "fifteen": num = 15;
                     break;
            case "sixteen": num = 16;
                     break;
            case "seventeen": num = 17;
                     break;
            case "eighteen": num = 18;
                     break;
            case "nineteen": num = 19;
                     break;
            case "twenty":  num = 20;
                     break;
            case "thirty":  num = 30;
                     break;
            case "forty":  num = 40;
                     break;
            case "fifty":  num = 50;
                     break;
            case "sixty":  num = 60;
                     break;
            case "seventy":  num = 70;
                     break;
            case"eighty":  num = 80;
                     break;
            case "ninety":  num = 90;
                     break; 
            case "hundred": num = 100;
                        break;
            case "thousand": num = 1000;
                        break;     
           /*default: num = "Invalid month";
                             break;*/
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```