# Check if a String is a number

Tags: java, android, string, int

I know you can check if a string is an integer by just doing `Integer.parseInt("1234");`
But what I want is to do is link a textual number to an integer.
i.e.

- "One" == 1
- "Two" == 2
- "Three" == 3
- "Twenty" == 20

Is there some library I can use to do this, or do I have to program this all by hand?

The reason I want to do this, is that I have an android application with speech recognition.
The user can then count. This number is shown on the screen.

**EDIT**
After some experimenting, I figured out that the SpeechRecognizer class I use automatically parses numbers to actual numbers...

Comment: You could use an enum pattern to accomplish this.

Comment: Just keep in mind, that this will have SERIOUS i18n problems.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062022/how-to-convert-words-to-number

Comment: @BYTERIDER thanks for the heads up, however the answer on that particular question was not sufficient. I wan't to focus more on the numbers 1-100. Not on the "one hundred seventy one" problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a library for that but [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0426.html) is a good example.

Answer (score 2):

As far I know there is no library for this but you can think like this

create three types of tokens

**a.** one, two, three.................... nine

**b.** eleven to nineteen, twenty, thirty , ............ ninety

**c.** hundred, thousand, ........ and bigger values

now parse your input string and match with your tokens. Just for a basic idea you can think like this

> step 1. create tokens from stirng tokenizer
>
> step 2. match the right most string and match with tokens
>
> step 3. match one by one string from right and match with tokens and
>   calculate

for example `ONE THOUSAND FIVE HUNDRED FIFTY THREE`

let sum =0

first string = THree so sum +=3

second string = FiFTY so sum += 50;

third string  = Hundred so you need to multiply fourth string with 100 and add so sum += f*100.. and so on

This is just a basic idea. So you can implement it perfectly after proper planning