# Converting characters to integers in Java

Tags: java, integer, type-conversion, character, primitive

Can someone please explain to me what is going on here:

```
char c = '+';
int i = (int)c;
System.out.println("i: " + i + " ch: " + Character.getNumericValue(c));
```

This prints `i: 43 ch:-1`. Does that mean I have to rely on primitive conversions to convert `char` to `int`? So how can I convert a `Character` to `Integer`?

**Edit:** Yes I know `Character.getNumericValue` returns `-1` if it is not a numeric value and that makes sense to me. The question is: why does doing primitive conversions return `43`?

**Edit2:** `43` is the ASCII for `+`, but I would expect the cast to not succeed just like `getNumericValue` did not succeed. Otherwise that means there are two semantic equivalent ways to perform the same operation but with different results?

Comment: What did you expect to get instead of `43`?

Comment: I don't think that `getNumericValue` does what you think it does.  That is a utility method that converts characters to integers (as in, the character '5' into the integer 5).  That is not the same as a cast (which converts the character '5' into the integer 53).

Comment: The point is that casting does not return the digit's numeric value.  Those two operations do two different things.

Answer (score 96):

```
Character.getNumericValue(c)
```

The `java.lang.Character.getNumericValue(char ch)` returns the `int` value that the specified Unicode character represents. For example, the character `'\u216C'` (the roman numeral fifty) will return an int with a value of 50.

The letters A-Z in their uppercase `('\u0041' through '\u005A')`, lowercase `('\u0061' through '\u007A')`, and full width variant `('\uFF21' through '\uFF3A' and '\uFF41' through '\uFF5A')` forms have numeric values from 10 through 35. This is independent of the Unicode specification, which does not assign numeric values to these char values.

> This method returns the numeric value of the character, as a
>   nonnegative int value;
>
> -2 if the character has a numeric value that is not a nonnegative integer;
>
> -1 if the character has no numeric value.

And [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29) is the link.

Answer (score 40):

As the documentation clearly states, `Character.getNumericValue()` returns the character's value as a digit.
It returns `-1` if the character is not a digit.

If you want to get the numeric Unicode code point of a boxed `Character` object, you'll need to unbox it first:

```
int value = (int)c.charValue();
```

Comment: You might want to link to that documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29

Answer (score 40):

Try any one of the below. These should work:

```
int a = Character.getNumericValue('3');
int a = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf('3');
```

Answer (score 2):

From the Javadoc for `Character#getNumericValue`:

> If the character does not have a numeric value, then -1 is returned.
>   If the character has a numeric value that cannot be represented as a
>   nonnegative integer (for example, a fractional value), then -2 is
>   returned.

The character `+` does not have a numeric value, so you're getting -1.

Update:

The reason that primitive conversion is giving you 43 is that the the character '+' is encoded as the integer 43.

Answer (score 1):

43 is the dec ascii number for the "+" symbol.  That explains why you get a 43 back.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Answer (score 0):

```
public class IntergerParser {

public static void main(String[] args){
String number = "+123123";
System.out.println(parseInt(number));
}

private static int parseInt(String number){
    char[] numChar = number.toCharArray();
    int intValue = 0;
    int decimal = 1;
    for(int index = numChar.length ; index > 0 ; index --){
        if(index == 1 ){
            if(numChar[index - 1] == '-'){
                return intValue * -1;
            } else if(numChar[index - 1] == '+'){
                return intValue;
            }
        }
        intValue = intValue + (((int)numChar[index-1] - 48) * (decimal));
        System.out.println((int)numChar[index-1] - 48+ " " + (decimal));
        decimal = decimal * 10;
    }
    return intValue;
}
```