# trouble understanding how this code works in java

Tags: java

```
public static boolean isVowel (char c){
    return "A,a,E,e,I,i,O,o,U,u".indexOf(c) != -1;
}
```

Can u guys explain the whole concept of this code? what does public static boolean isvowel do?
what does return do? and what does .indexOf(c) do and mean? and why use a -1 there?
thanks for the help

Comment: You should read up here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html. Actually, start at the beginning over here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: In addition to the other answers, it's worth noting that passing `','` (comma) will qualify as a vowel according to this function. It would be better to be `"AaEeIiOoUu".indexOf(c) != -1`.

Answer (score 0):

A character can be automatically casted to a number. It is *not* necessarily equal to the *display value* of that character.

So any int-parameter, such as in `indexOf(i)` can also accept a `char`. However, unless you know what you are doing, it is likely a mistake.

There is some more information about this in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388037/converting-characters-to-integers-in-java).

As far as the `-1`, that is answered by the [JavaDoc of `indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29). It is one of its possible return values.

Answer (score 0):

This is checking if the argument to the function is a vowel. .indexOf() returns -1 if the value is not found. So if the value is not found in the list of vowels, it will return -1. -1 != -1 is False so passing a consonant into isVowel() will return False, while passing a vowel will return True.