# Java character conversion to numerical encoding

Tags: java

How am I to convert a char into its numerical encoding value?

The code I used is

```
public class Q1A {
    int toInt(char character){
        int getInt = toInt(character);
        return getInt;
    }
}
```

Sorry if my question is hard to understand

Comment: Just `int toInt(char character){
   return character;      
}`

Answer (score 1):

you just need

```
int toInt(char character){
   int  i = (int) character; // this will gives int value(ASCII) of char.
   return i;
}
```

Or you can simplify to

```
int toInt(char character){
   return (int) character;      
}
```

You can use `Character.getNumericValue(c)` too to get numeric value . More about [Character.getNumericValue(c)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388037/converting-characters-to-integers-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you want to actual numeric value of the char or the ascii value or somthing similar

```
//Get numeric value
int toInt(char c)
{
   return Character.getNumericValue(c);
}

//Get ascii value
int toInt(char c)
{
   return (int)c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the ASCII value of a char?

```
int toInt(char character) {
    return (int)character
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use java Character class

Character.getNumericValue(char)