# Char to int and back again

Tags: java, char

I want to find an integer representation of a character, then later on find a character representation of an int.

My current solution is this, but it doesn't work:

```
String s = "A"
Integer b = Character.getNumericValue(s.toCharArray()[0]);    // 10
char c = Character.toChars(b)[0];                             // (blank)
```

How should i do this?

Comment: It's not a blank character: it is `\u000a`, which is a newline.

Comment: It isn't clear what you expect: what do you think should be in `c`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984975/convert-int-to-char-in-java

Comment: Are you confused about `getNumericValue`? This method converts a char like `'5'` to its numerical value of `5`. It does not return the ASCII code  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388037/converting-characters-to-integers-in-java In short, what is confusing you and what were you expecting instead at each line?

Comment: Note: `s.charAt(0)` is a lot more efficient than `s.toCharArray()[0]`, since the latter makes a copy of the entire string into an array, of which you only read a single element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a misunderstanding in how `Character.getNumericValue(char)` works.

> Returns the int value that the specified Unicode character represents. For example, the character '\u216C' (the roman numeral fifty) will return an int with a value of 50.
>
> The letters A-Z in their uppercase ('\u0041' through '\u005A'), lowercase ('\u0061' through '\u007A'), and full width variant ('\uFF21' through '\uFF3A' and '\uFF41' through '\uFF5A') forms have numeric values from 10 through 35. This is independent of the Unicode specification, which does not assign numeric values to these char values.

from the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29).

In other words:
The method `getNumericValue` does **not** produce the UTF-16 value of the specified character, but attempts to produce a numeric value - in the sense that '0' will produce 0 - from the given value. And 'A' corresponds to 10 in hex.

But 10 is **not** the UTF16 value corresponding to 'A'.

A correct way of converting a `char` to it's corresponding UTF16-value would be to use one of the codepoint-methods from `Character`. Or if you're absolutely positive, all values will be of the BMP, you can use

```
char c = 'A';
int i = (int) c;
```

In this case `Character.toChars(int)` will also work.

Answer (score 0):

```
int b = s.charAt(0); // 65
char c = (char) b  // 'A'
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to have written `char c = s.charAt(0);`?

Comment: Of course, but I was trying to relate the answer to the steps the OP was taking.

Comment: Just missing out the `Character.getNumericValue` bit... :)