# Averaging two characters based on their ASCII value

Tags: java

I am new to java programming. I am having a problem on how to use the method for `char` here. What do you return in the `char` method to get the average of the ASCII values in the main body? Thanks!

```
public static int average(int i,int j)
{
    return (i + j) / 2;
}

public static double average(double a,double b)
{
    return (a + b) / 2;
}

public static char average(char first,char second)
{
    return ?;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    char first = 'a', second = 'b';
    int i = 5, j = 12;
    double a = 5.5, b = 8.5;

    System.out.println("Average of (x,y) is : " + average(first,second));
    System.out.println("Average of (a,b) is : " + average(a,b));
    System.out.println("Average of (i,j) is : " + average(i,j));
}
```

Comment: a char is a number, just like an int.

Comment: Try this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388037/converting-characters-to-integers-in-java#answer-19388099

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chars are at the end ints, so the average char makes no much sense since the result will be char again, i.e consider this case:
what is the average between 'a' and 'b'? a is represented with 97, b with 98, ave = 97.5 but there is no char value for 97.5, in fact, that will be rounded to int pointing to 97 again, so  average for 'a' and 'b' is 'a', kind of weird isnt ?

Anyway you can do

```
public static char average(char first,char second)
{
    return (char) (  (first + second) / 2);
}
```

note that since dividing by int literal **2** you will need to cast the result to char again..

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `char` values are automatically typecasted to `int` type.

As you have already got `average(int i,int j)`, you don't need to write any `average(char first,char second)`.

So when you call `average(first,second))`, then the method which take `int` arguments i.e., `average(int i,int j)` will be invoked.