# Converting a real string integer (e.g. "thirty five") to integer

Tags: java

Is there a way to convert an English `string` representation of an integer (e.g. "one hundred eighty") to an integer? As expected `Integer.parseInt("thirty five")` threw a `NumberFormatException`. Is there a built in function in Java to do this?

Comment: No, there is not built-in info for this. Instead, create your own map and parse the string manually or search for such implementation on the net.

Comment: There's been some interesting discussion on the reverse algorithm here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java Maybe that can help you get started.

Comment: I would vote to close as duplicate, but that other one is also closed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**

No, there is no built-in functionality to achieve this.

**1. Approach: HashMap**

You can use a HashMap to store the String, Integer pair (e.g.: "twenty" and 20).

```
HashMap<String, Integer> numbers = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

numbers.put("one", 1);
numbers.put("two", 2);

...

numbers.put("nine", 9);
numbers.put("ten", 10);
numbers.put("eleven", 11);

...

numbers.put("twenty", 20);
numbers.put("thirty", 30);

...
```

Then you can simply parse it via numbers.get(..) and add that number to your resulting number.

```
public int getNumber(String str)
{
   int number = 0;
   String[] parts = str.split(" ");

   for (String number : parts)
   {
        if (numbers.contains(number)
        {
            number += parts.get(number);
        }
   } 

   return number;
}
```

**2. Approach: ArrayList**

You can create an ArrayList like

```
ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>;

numbers.add("zero");
numbers.add("one");

...

numbers.add("eight");
numbers.add("nine");    
numbers.add("ten");

...
```

Then you could build your own function to parse a String to those numbers by looking them up in this ArrayList (their index is the resulting number).

```
public int getNumber(String str)
{
   int number = 0;
   String[] parts = str.split(" ");

   for (String number : parts)
   {
        if (numbers.contains(number)
        {
            number += parts.indexof(number);
        }
   } 

   return number;
}
```

**See also**

- [How to convert words to a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062022/how-to-convert-words-to-number)
- [How to convert number to words in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Try to split the String by it's white spaces, then replace each word for it's corresponding number.

You can have a `Map<String, Integer>` with the words and numbers.

Comment: @1337 I think your ArrayList implementation has a problem, but I can't comment on your answer. For the input "one hundred eighty" it would return '10080', wouldn't it?

Comment: You are absolutely right, the ArrayList implementation has flaws yeah, that's why I included the HashMap implementation too :)

Comment: @1337 Then delete it, leave just the other one :)

Comment: I don't want to edit that part out because it is another interesting approach, I like the idea to use index-of for that - can be useful for some other things too :)