# C# Speech Recognition - convert sentence into numbers

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, calculator

I'm learning C# through a calculator project, and am trying to add a cool feature that can recognize voice as calculator input.  The System.Speech.Recognition library has allowed me to easily add grammar choices for numbers 0-9 with some basic if statement code.  However, I want it to be able to recognize all possible combinations of numbers that a user could say...what's the best approach for this without having to hand code every possible combination of numbers as a sentence/string (e.g. "five hundred thirty seven thousand four hundred twenty two")?

Here's what I have so far:

```
private void buttonListen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    SpeechRecognitionEngine speechRecognize = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

    Choices ones = new Choices();
    ones.Add(new string[] { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" });

    Grammar calculatorGrammerOnes = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(ones));

    try
        {
            speechRecognize.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
            speechRecognize.LoadGrammar(calculatorGrammerOnes);
            speechRecognize.SpeechRecognized += speechRecognize_SpeechRecognized;
            speechRecognize.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            speechRecognize.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        }
    catch
        {
            return;
        }
 }

private void speechRecognize_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Result.Text == "one")
    {
      //Insert "1" as the operand
    }
    else if (e.Result.Text == "two")
    {
      //Insert "2" as the operand
    }
etc...
 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062022/how-to-convert-words-to-number

Answer (score 0):

That would be much complex

> e.g. "five hundred thirty seven thousand four hundred twenty two",

If in the same scenario one provide input speech as :

"five hundred and thirty seven thousand four hundred twenty two"

your algorithm cannot find the result.

It would be much easier if inputs are like :

> eg. "five three seven zero ..etc "