# Android Speech to text for number and email ID

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech-synthesis, android-speech-api

I am  using Android Speech to text for speech recognition.

```
 final Intent sttIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    sttIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

    final String language = config.getLanguage().replace('-', '_');

    sttIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, language);
    sttIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, language);
    sttIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);
    sttIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, context.getPackageName());

    // WORKAROUND for https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75347
    sttIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.EXTRA_ADDITIONAL_LANGUAGES", new String[]{language});
    return sttIntent;
```

**I am having problem while getting phone number and email id.
It is not giving proper results.**

**Suppose if user say "triple two triple three five hundred one"
In this case STT should give me 222333501, but it is giving some number and string as result.**

**Suppose if user say "abc_cde@gmail.com", in this case also it is giving at the rate of and underscore as strings.**

Is there any native way to solve this problem. 
I have referred a java utility  [Convert words to number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17324733/3787344) to convert string to number if valid but i am not sure that would work in all cases. 
Any help is appreciated.